# plsql stored procedure syntax error

Tags: syntax, plsql, procedure

when I try the following code, I get a procedure completed with 0 compilation errors.. message instead of procedure successfully completed message.
what's wrong with this? and help me in correcting this error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE omar_manager_report1 (
   pi_co_id          IN       VARCHAR2,                          -- Company ID
   pi_cntr_nbr       IN       NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
   -- if Contract number is passed then Case 1: will be executed
   pi_overdue_days   IN       NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
   --No of days related to Over due of application passed.
   po_var_ref        OUT      sys_refcursor
)
IS
   lv_query   VARCHAR2(400) ;
   lv_co_id   VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
   lv_co_id := REPLACE (pi_co_id, ',', ''',''');
   --Default option for all group office
   lv_query :=
      'select distinct gue.co_id,
      (SELECT event_descp FROM get_event WHERE co_id = gue.co_id AND event_cd = gue.event_cd) AS event_desc
       FROM get_uwtg_event gue';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('lv_query');

   OPEN po_var_ref FOR lv_query;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLCODE);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing a `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE...` statement *compiles* the procedure, but it does not *call* the procedure. You'll need to write a PL/SQL block similar to the following to invoke your procedure:

```
DECLARE
  csrOut   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  omar_manager_report1(pi_co_id        => '123456',
                       pi_cntr_nbr     => 0,
                       pi_overdue_days => 0,
                       po_var_ref      => csrOut);

  -- Add code here to fetch from csrOut and use the results appropriately

  -- Close the cursor opened by omar_manager_report1

  CLOSE csrOut;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: ' || SQLCODE || ' : ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Bob!  thanks for the reply. however the procedure is not compiling properly in the first place .it gets a "compiled with 0 errors and 0 warnings" . so I need help in fixing the error with compilation .

Comment: OK, execute the following statement: `SELECT * FROM SYS.USER_ERRORS WHERE NAME = 'OMAR_MANAGER_REPORT1' AND TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'`. This will retrieve all the compilation errors for your procedure. Then edit your question, include the errors, and hopefully someone will be able to help. Thanks.